# SQL Server: Handle of string concatenation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given a variable nvarchar(max), the input is 'aaaaa...' with 16000 length.
The value of the variable has no problem with this setup.

If I break down the input into 3 smaller ones let's say (7964,4594,3442) the variable truncates the concatenation of them.

On the other hand, if at least 1 variable is over 8000 size, the concatenation works without an issue.

Is there any documentation regarding the mentioned behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using CONCAT function

> If none of the input arguments has a supported large object (LOB)
>   type, then the return type truncates to 8000 characters in length,
>   regardless of the return type. This truncation preserves space and
>   supports plan generation efficiency.

try

```
CONCAT(CAST('' as VARCHAR(MAX)),@var1,@var2)
```

or

```
CAST(@var1 as VARCHAR(MAX)) + @var2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Tip: It's good practice to include a link to the documentation (or other examples) that you're citing, e.g. [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks). It makes it easier for readers to learn more and avoids anyone claiming that you are pretending to be the author of the cited material.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of
>   8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the
>   strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur.

Operations between varchar and nvarchar are limited to 8000 and 4000 characters respectively, unless you treat any of the involved data types as `MAX`. Please be very cautious with the order of the operations, this is a very good example from the docs:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(8000) = replicate('x', 8000)
DECLARE @y varchar(max) = replicate('y', 8000)
DECLARE @z varchar(8000) = replicate('z',8000)

SET @y = @x + @z + @y

-- The result of following select is 16000
SELECT len(@y) AS y
```

The result is 16k and not 24k because the first operation is `@x + @z` which is truncated at 8000 because neither of them are `MAX`. Then the result is concatenated to a type that is `MAX`, thus breaking the restriction of 8000 as limit, which adds another 8000 characters from `@y`. In the result, the characters from variable `@z` are lost at the first concatenation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! I did not know about the exception of Large Objects.